# 'XXX' is not public when config servlet in web.xml - IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea

I am puzzled when I config the servlet in the `web.xml`:

> com.ypd.web5.FirstServlet' is not public

[image]

Code is below:

```
<!-- config my servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ypd.web5.FirstServlet</servlet-class>  /* there I got the error */
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I can not find why I get this issue, any help will be grateful.

---

**Addition**

```
package com.ypd.web5; 
/**
 * Created by ldl on 2017/2/4.
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doGet(req, response);

        response.getWriter().write("This is first servlet!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also include the definition for the `FirstServlet` class, assuming that it will fit?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, Tim, I am not very understand your mean. how to include the definition for the `FirstServlet`?

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, I know where is the mistake, caused by the FirstServlet definition, thank you.

Comment: `public class FirstServlet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare servlet class and the methods init, service and destroy as public because the server should be able to access these. This is very similar to the main method declaring with the access modifier public.
Another reason is in HttpServlet and in GenericServlet classes, these three methods are public whose access level you can not reduce in inherited classes.

So check if your FirstServlet class is declared as public class.

Comment: thank you, my class did not set public class, only class